# How to upload Image to Web APP (Asp.net) and hold it for processing?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I am trying to create a web app using asp.net (trying to get some knowledge in order to work on more advanced stuff later on). The app I'm trying to make needs to have a picture uploaded to it and then do some processing to it. Now the question, Can I have the user upload this picture display it on the page and hold it somewhere temporarily for processing without making use of a database?

Tried looking through YouTube and web but couldn't find any specific documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gee, I don't see why a database would matter?

If you don't have a database, that should not effect that you can just drop in a file up loader, up-load files to say some folder, and then display the list of files that been up-loaded. And you are 100% free to THEN process those files later that been dropped into that folder, right?

So, lets drop in a file up-loader (you can choose/use one of a "gazillion" such up-loaders, or use a simple fileupload control.

Right below that control, then drop in say a grid view to display the files you up-loaded into that folder.

So, say this markup:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" height="40px"
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="rMyChoice"  ClientIDMode="Static"
    AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Upload Files</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>My Files</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<br />

<div id="uploadfiles" runat="server" style="width:550px">
    <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
        OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" 
        OnClientUploadCompleteAll="AllDone" />
</div>

<div id="myfiles" runat="server" style="width: 700px">
<asp:GridView ID="GridFiles" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" CssClass="table table-hover" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Created" HeaderText="UpLoaded" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Size" HeaderText="Size" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="120px"
                    ImageUrl='<%# "UpLoadFiles/" + Eval("FileName") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdDownLoad"
                    runat="server" Text="Download" CssClass="btn"
                    OnClick="cmdDownLoad_Click"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FileName") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
</div>
```

I am using the ajaxtoolkit up-loader, but it kind of don't really matter here at all.

Then below the up-loader, I just dropped in a grid view to display the files after up-loading.

Heck, might as well use a tab control, or a simple radio button list, so the user can view files, or up-load some more.

So, with above, I have this code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    RBShow()

End Sub


Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim rstFiles As New DataTable

    rstFiles.Columns.Add("FileName")
    rstFiles.Columns.Add("Created", GetType(DateTime))
    rstFiles.Columns.Add("Size")

    Dim sFolder As String = "~/UpLoadFiles"
    Dim MyFolder As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(sFolder))

    Dim MyFileList() As FileInfo = MyFolder.GetFiles("*.*")

    For Each OneFile As FileInfo In MyFileList
        Dim OneRow As DataRow = rstFiles.NewRow
        OneRow("FileName") = OneFile.Name
        OneRow("Created") = OneFile.CreationTime.ToString("G")
        OneRow("Size") = OneFile.Length
        rstFiles.Rows.Add(OneRow)
    Next

    GridFiles.DataSource = rstFiles
    GridFiles.DataBind()


End Sub


Protected Sub RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    RBShow()

End Sub

Sub RBShow()

    ' routine to hide and show a div based on radio button (this is our fake tab control)


    If RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then

        uploadfiles.Style.Add("Display", "normal")
        myfiles.Style.Add("Display", "none")
    Else
        LoadGrid()
        uploadfiles.Style.Add("Display", "none")
        myfiles.Style.Add("Display", "normal")

    End If


End Sub
```

The file uploader has a up-load file complete event. That code is simple this:

```
Protected Sub AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs)

    Dim sFile As String = Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadFiles/") & e.FileName

    AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(sFile)


End Sub
```

So, when we run the page, we get this:

[image]

So, since you don't have a database - don't need one!

Then just load up a grid view, or listbox or whatever with a list of files from the folder you save all the files being up-loaded.

of course in above, I do have a download button.

that code looks like this:

```
Protected Sub cmdDownLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim myBut As Button = sender
    Dim strFileOnly As String = myBut.CommandArgument
    Dim strFile As String = ""
    strFile = Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadFiles/" + strFileOnly)


    Dim sMineType As String = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(strFileOnly)

    Response.ContentType = sMineType
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileOnly)
    Response.TransmitFile(strFile)
    Response.End()


End Sub
```

So, the files are still in that folder for "later" processing.

And even better, if you go back to the page, you can "view" the list of files already up-loaded, or up-load a few more.

So, it not at all clear why a database is required. Those files are just sitting in a folder.

You can then process those files, say when done move to another folder called MyProcessed.

And then you are free to up-load more files for processing that will reside in that MyUpLoads folder.